# MYSQL concat request and string substraction

Tags: mysql, string, request, concatenation

I have a mysql table below:

```
id   user_id   ticket 
1    39        56478939
2    51        42234951
3    40        56478940
4    52        67284952
```

Where ticket (for example for first row) =  564789 + 39 (user_id)
My request looks like:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(";", id, user_id, ticket) FROM `signals`
```

And I will get:

```
1;39;56478939
2;51;42234951
...
```

How can I get this type of data using MYSQL request (remove from ticket user_id at the end of ticket):

```
1;39;564789
2;51;422349
...
```

The request should be fast enough:
Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(";", id, user_id, LEFT(ticket,length(ticket)-length(user_id))) from table1;
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed2ad/9)**

Comment: We don't know ticket length or length of user_id

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
           SELECT CONCAT_WS(";", id, user_id, LEFT(ticket,6)) FROM `signals`
```

Comment: @user889349 I've assumed your ticket length would be 6. Consider Joe's answer if its dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(";", id, user_id, left(ticket,length(ticket)-length(user_id)))
FROM `signals`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query -

```
SELECT (ticket - user_id) DIV
  CASE
    WHEN user_id < 10 THEN 10
    WHEN user_id < 100 THEN 100
    ELSE 1000 END
FROM signals;
```

Add more WHEN cases if you need.

Then apply it to your query.